# .NET Overload WebMethods - Possible?

Tags: .net, web-services, overloading, webmethod

I have two web methods which I wish to overload:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetProject(ByVal id As Int32) As Project

<WebMethod(MessageName:="GetProjects")> _
Public Function GetProject(ByVal filter As String) As Projects
```

I read about overloading using MessageName, however I cannot get this to work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Off course it is possible!

do not forget to change the WebServiceBinding `[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.None)]`

try this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.None)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]    
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod(MessageName = "GetTime")]
    public string GetTime()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
    }

    [WebMethod(MessageName = "GetTimeWithName")]
    public string GetTime(string userName)
    {
        return "Hello " + userName + " it is " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
    }

    [WebMethod(MessageName = "GetTimeWithNameAndRepetitions")]
    public string GetTime(string userName, int repetitions)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;
        for(int i=0; i<repetitions; i++)
            response +=  "Hello " + userName + " it is " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "\n";
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible.
Hope this link will help: http://forums.asp.net/t/1162934.aspx