# Passing data to WebMethod() using jQuery

Tags: jquery, vb.net, web-services, webmethod

I am calling a WebMethod() using $.ajax() and it doesn't seem like the VB is handling the data correctly.

Here is my JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/RemoveUser",
    data: "{'s':'test'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

And I created two RemoveUser functions, below:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function RemoveUser(ByVal s As String) As String
    Return s
End Function
```

and

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function RemoveUser() As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
```

However, when I execute the above JS I get "true" returned. It is passing the data correctly:

[image: POST data]

Commenting out the RemoveUser(ByVal s As String) function does not change behavior at all.

Comment: I've been doing some googling...just wondering:
Are you sure it's supposed to be "{'s':'test'}" ? It looks like it might need to be '{"s":"test"}'

Comment: @sacredfaith: No change when swapping the quotes; good idea, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using overloading methods here:

Check this out: [.NET Overload WebMethods - Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921142/net-overload-webmethods-possible)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the quotes, the data element can be an object. Currently you were passing nothing...
Try this:

```
data: {"s":"test"},
```