# Web Services aspx Property of class doesn't keep default value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I'm Making a aspx web Services in vb.net. I receive an object array parameter letting the framework worry about cast validations as you can see

```
   <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString:=False)> _
       <WebMethod(True)> _
    Public Function insertarUnidad(ByVal unidades() As unidad) As String
```

and I have a public class defined

```
Public Class unidad

Public Property id_unidad As String
Public Property nombre As String ="I'm Not Empty"
Public Property placas As String = "N"
END Class
```

it turns out that when I'm debugging, the Object arrays doesn't have the default values of some propertys like placas, instead they have "0" value Which is the default value of String data type. but somehow the in the property nombre it does have the default value "I'm Not Empty".

how can I use the default value that I'm putting in the properties without losing it?

Thanks, sorry for my bad English.

**UPDATE**

The aspx was on .net4.5 and from web app it was working perfectly, but in a console app wasn't working because the console app was on net4.0 
it get fixed changing the framework target from 4.5 to 4.0,
Even if the console app is in 4.5 framework the aspx works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even a "" empty string will override those values.  But this is a good use case of a Get and a Set for the properties!

```
Public Class unidad
    Private _nombre as string
    Private _placas as string
    Public Property id_unidad As String Public Property placas
        Get
            Return _placas
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If value = "0" then
               _placas = "N"
            else
               _placas = value
            end if
        End Set 
    End Property
    Public Property nombre
            Get
                Return _nombre
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                If value = "0" then
                   _nombre = "I'm Not Empty"
                else
                   _nombre = value
                end if
            End Set
    End Property
End Class
'Your if statements may need changed
```

Comment: Using get/set for the properties it isn't working as expected, sometimes  the attribute has the default value of the property, sometimes i receive Nothing instead of "0", how could I know when I'm gonna receive Nothing or "0" in String, int, chat, decimal etc.


thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you saying sometimes the method doesn't even receive the additional values?  You would then need to create a new, overloaded version of this.  [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921142/net-overload-webmethods-possible)

Comment: No, when I receive an array, the framework will try to cast the array to **unidad** type Which means that some properties of the class will be overwritten with the value of the array's attributes, but, sometimes i will not receive all the class properties in the array's attributes, that's why I set a default value in the class properties like **nombre** with "I'm Not Empty". Inside the function I have an Object array of type **unidad** with the values received and the default values in case that some values where not received

Comment: The problem was that when I was trying to use the default value inside de function, it turns out that the default value was overwritten by the framework with the default value of data type of each property. 
this problem were solved changing framework's version from 4.5 to 4.0

Sorry for the delay and thanks for your time.